# Implied volatility of Asian options under Black76 model

Tags: options, implied-volatility

I found this  [repository](https://github.com/dedwards25/Python_Option_Pricing/blob/master/GBS.ipynb) (options pricing in Python) where they adjust IV for Asian options and they use it under the regular BS76 model.

I could not find any proof of this result on the web, do you know any paper where a similar result is proved or do you have any idea from where to start?

[image: formula]

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [Turnbull-Wakeman approximation](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10203-020-00283-x#:%7E:text=The%20original%20Turnbull%20and%20Wakeman,average%20of%20the%20futures%20price.) for pricing continuous arithmetic average options adjusted for the case of option on futures. Please note that this approximation has some serious limitations and works well for low volatilities ($~20-30\%$) and short tenors (up to $2-3$ years).

Comment: thank you for pointing that out.